# Впрос по JQuery: авторизация без перезагрузки

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript, css

Подскажите, кто знает, как сделать авторизацию на сайте без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: Отправляете аякс-запрос на сервер, авторизуете в фоне, отдаёте сервером необходимые данные, которые нужно заменить, и потом заменяете на странице, откуда авторизовывались.

Answer (score 1):

1. Есть форма регистрации
2. Заполняются поля и наживается "Авторизоваться"
3. По клику отправляется запрос с передачей данных ($.post)
4. На сервере данные получаются, обрабатываются, если все правильно, но происходит авторизация, иначе вывод ошибки в формате "json" например.

Обработка клика:

```
$('#send_button').click(function(){
    var login = $('#login').val(); //логин
    var password = $('#password').val(); //пароль

    $.post('/auth_url.php', {login: login, passw: password}, function(result){
         //тут работа с ответом сервера через объект result
    }, 'json');
});
```

Comment: Человек просил авторизацию, а не регистрацию. Хотя принцип тот же :)  
Ваша функция перезагрузит страницу, добавьте return false; в конец обработки клика.

Comment: Перезагрузка будет только если использовать обработку клика на ссылке или кнопке типа Submit. Если же сделать ссылку без href="" или тип button, то не нужно.

Comment: только ненадо забывать что если при авторизации нужно еще и поменять кое где контент или добавить блоки которые ранее невидимы или еще чтото то лучше перезагрузить страницу.

Comment: Я решал этот вопрос так: на сервере выполняются действия и если успешно, то возвращается html код(ссылка на личный кабинет), который через js вставляется в шапку сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь описывал примерный алгоритм: [как сделать форму регистрации авторизации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/34572/#34722).

Answer (score 0):

Стартуете сессию на любых страницах сайта . Тогда вы сможете подставить в нее необходимые данные сессии без перезагрузок.

Отправляете $.post() данные из формы. Если данные валидны - устанавливаете необходимые переменные сессии на сервере. В случае с php они уже должны работать с неперезагруженной страницей, так как сессия была создана перед авторизацией.