# Как сделать форму регистрации-авторизации на сайте?

Tags: авторизация, регистрация, php

Как сделать, чтобы она не перенаправляла на другую страницу, а появлялось окно, в которое нужно вводить данные, и чтобы после авторизации появлялся логин человека. Или напишите, где об этом почитать. Большое спасибо!

Comment: На каком языке? PHP, Python, Ruby?..

Comment: Я думаю,что php,чтобы потом в html код вставить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаем средствами css div который будет у нас играть роль окна. CSS прелести описывать не буду т.к. и так  довльно таки обьемный код получится, я не фанат jquery поэтому его вы в моем коде не увидете.

```
<span id="loginShow">Войти</span>
<div id="login">
    <imput type="text" id="username">
    <input type="password" id="password">
    <button id="authAction">Войти</button>
    <div id="loginResult">
        <!-- Тут мы будем отображать ответ сервера -->
    </div>
</div>
```

ну вот "окошко" както так... терь PHP, как вы будете описывать обработку попытки входа дело ваше. Ну например:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
         // тут мы както будем проверять в бд...
         // допустим у нас в теле условия формируется переменная
         // в которой лежит 'OK' либо сообщение об ошибке
         if($authResult == 'OK') {
              // тут мы непосредственно делаем авторизацию пользователя
         }
         echo $authResult; // Выводим результат
    }
}
```

ну и теперь мы дошли до JS:

var authRequest = new XMLHtppRequest();

```
function showLoginBox() {
    document.getElementById("login").style.display = "block";
}

onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'none'; //прячем формочку
    document.getElementById('loginShow').onclick = showLoginBox; //при нажатии на спан - показываем формочку

    // Для удобства запишу в обьект authRequest некоторые елементы
    authRequest.username = document.getElementById('username');
    authRequest.password = document.getElementById('password');
    authRequert.result = document.getElementById('loginResult');
}
authRequest.loginTry = function () {
    if(this.username.value != '') {
         if(this.password.value != '') {
              this.data = "username="+this.username.value+"password="+this.password.value;
              this.doLogin();
         }
         else {
             this.result.innerHTML = 'Вы не ввели пароль'
         }
    }
    else {
         this.result.innerHTML = 'Вы не ввели логин';
         return;
}
authRequest.doLogin = function() {
    this.open("POST", "http://путь_к_твоему_php_скрипту.php", true);
    this.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //говорим серверу что мы отправляем POST формочку
    this.send(this.data); // собственно отправляем
}
authRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
   //тут мы отлавливаем когда пришел ответ сервера на нашу отправку формочки
   if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       result = this.responseText;  //в this.responseText хранится ответ сервера
       if(result == 'OK') {  //если все ок и пользователь зареган
           this.result.innerHTML = 'Вы успешно авторизованы';
           document.getElementById("login").style.display = "none";
       }
       else {
           this.result.innerHTML = result;
       }
   }
}
```

ну думаю тут понятно что при успешной авторизации уже можно средствами JS как-то перерисовать.
можно даже сделать еще один ajax запрос на другой скрипт, это уже не суть, если я вас правильно понял -  алгоритм примерно такой
Код не тестил, накидал прямо на сайте так что если где ошибки - уж извините :)

Answer (score 0):

По клику показываете окошко формы(скрытый блок), в этом окне по клику на отправку формы делаете аякс-запрос на страницу авторизации и передаёте форму, авторизовываете и возвращаете ответ: прошла авторизация успешно или нет. Если успешно - перезагружаете страницу либо меняете контент, это уже по необходимости и желанию. Если не успешно - показываете ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

точно вопроса не понял, но могу подсказать все, что понял:
Вот тебе примерный код(все, что пришло в голову перед сном):

```
<?php
session_start();
//тут какой нибудь код
if(isset($_GET['do']))
{
  if($_GET['do']=="exit")
  session_destroy();
}
if(isset($_POST['btn']))
{
 if($_POST['btn']=="Авторизироваться")
  {
     //Процесс Авторизации
     //Если все в порядке
    //вводите данные в сессию
    $_SESSION['auth']=true;
    $_SESSION['name']='Имя';

  }

}
if($_SESSION['auth'])
{
  if($_SESSION['auth'])
  {
    echo 'Вы авторизованны как - '.$_SESSION['name'].'<br /><a href="?do=exit">Выход</a>';
  }
  else
  {
  //Тут форма для авторизации
   echo '
  <form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="login"><br />
  <input type="password" name="pass"><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Авторизироваться" name="btn">
  </form>
  ';
  }
}
?>
```