# MVC client validation при загрузке в jQuery UI dialog частичного представления

Tags: jquery, mvc

Можно ли как-то использовать MVC client validation если загружать в jquery ui dialog какое-то частичное представление ?

Есть задача, например, добавление нового пользователя. На странице нажимаем на кнопочку, открывается диалоговое окошко (сделанное с использованием jquery ui dialog). В содержимое диалогового окна загружается частичное представление, которое содержит поля ввода для создания пользователя и кнопку добавить. Как проще всего реализовать клиентскую валидацию полей внутри диалогового окна?

Если бы форма не открывалась внутри диалога, можно было бы просто добавить к модели, с которой связано частичное представление атрибуты Required и т.д. и добавить на страницу стандартные jquery скрипты для валидации jquery.validate.min.js и jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js и к текстовым полям ввода добавить в представлении элементы Html.ValidationMessage. Или простого способа нет и надо самому писать проверку ввода при нажатии на кнопку "добавить пользователя"?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то похожее я описывал здесь: [Как сделать форму регистрации-авторизации на сайте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/34722)

Учим *js*, валидация легко и просто пишется самому без плагинов и *jquery*.