# Нужна авторизация на сайте по ключу (html)

Tags: авторизация

Создал сайт (одностраничник). Но хочу, чтобы к контенту имели доступ люди, которые при заходе на сайт вводили ключ в окне, которое бы им показывалось, и чтобы я предварительно генерировал ключ.

Comment: На чистом html вам этого не сделать. Нужно использовать язык программирования для back-end. Поизучайте тему и отредактируйте свой вопрос, дополнив его информацией о языке программирования, структуре всего проекта и другими деталями. А пока на ваш вопрос нельзя дать однозначного ответа.

Comment: посоветуйте мне хотя бы с чего начать. 
Я просто хочу сделать вот такой алгоритм работы:
- Пользователь заходит на сайт
- Видит окно авторизации(просто окно для ввода ключа и кнопка для подтверждения действия) 
- Вводит ключ, который я ему дал, и далее его перенаправляет на страницу, которая мне нужна. 
По типу
Если ключ верный - перенаправление на страницу
Если ключ неверный - закрытие страницы

Comment: @user198445 вам уже порекомендовали поизучать тему, определиться с языком для back-end и т.д.

Comment: Тут не все так просто.... Надо ведь еще помнить, что человек уже авторизован, когда он был перенаправлен на Вашу страницу. Что если он запомнил URL и просто введет ее в след. раз в адресной строке? Есть еще несколько нюансов. Так что совет @LEQADA абсолютно верен. Теоретически, для описанной Вами проблемы, подойдет любой язык веб-программирования. Выбирайте.

Comment: @user198445, я тут нашёл [похожий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/34572/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5). Это то, от чего можно хотя бы оттолкнуться.

Comment: @LEQADA А апчевская авторизация? или совсем плохая?

Comment: @splash58, этот вопрос предназначен для меня? Если да, то я не понимаю о чём вы.

Comment: Чтоб ничего не писать - например http://www.softtime.ru/info/apache.php?id_article=27

Comment: @splash58, а как вы будете генерировать ключ?

Comment: @LEQADA там какая-то приблуда была. я в начале 90 это пользовал. деталей не помню уже :( потому с сомнением и спросил :)

Answer (score 1):

к примеру, вы можете использовать [http basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

например, в случае [http-сервера apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) внутри блока directory можно указать примерно следующее:

```
<directory />
  authtype basic
  authname "restricted"
  authuserfile /путь/к/файлу/с/паролями
  require valid-user
</directory>
```

где файл `/путь/к/файлу/с/паролями` — созданный вами, например, с помощью программы `htpasswd`.